# Running and Testing AWS API Gateway via Browser instead of postman or curl

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway

Could anyone please share how to run and test AWS API Gateway and Lambda via Browser and not via Postman or curl.
I am trying to create a simple demo app using HTML + JavaScript (with ajax call to API), and calling the AWS API.
I did tried with postman and curl both are working fine, however when calling from browser (ajax call) it is failing.

Any pointer will be a great.

code snippet :

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : URL,
        dataType: "json",
        mode: 'no-cors',
        crossDomain: "true",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),

        success: function () {
            // clear form and show a success message
            alert("Your entry is saved Successfuly");
            document.getElementById("my-form").requestFullscreen();
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function() {
            // show an error message
            alert("Seems some issue with the entry, try again.")
        }
    });
```

This is a simple demo as of now to get the User Name and other details and save it into DynamoDB via AWS Lambda (Python).
AWS Lambda function is being called but in the Response it fails.

Sample code is https://codepen.io/mayanktripathi4u/pen/QWdrPOG
Tried with various options using JS Fetch; ajax; XMLHttpResponse etc.. non worked.

Comment: Your codepen.io example works for me, that is: the Lambda-function does return a value. The only error I see is that you're trying to parse a normal string (`This is my Response from Lambda Function.`) as JSON

Comment: @mayank-tripathi What is the expected behaviour that you need? As mentioned by Bert, the response is getting logged in the console. It's just that you are trying to parse the response which is already a string to JSON.

Comment: Thanks @BertBlommers, this helps. I did corrected the response, and its working now.